# jQuery Ajax get value via function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a `save(id)` function that will submit ajax post request. When calling a `save(id)`. How to get value/data from `save(id)` before going to next step. How to solve this?

For example:

```
        function save(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/post/",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    id: id,
                }),
                success: function (data) {
                 return data;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                return data;
                }
            });
        }
```

Usage:

```
$('.btn-create').click(function () {
  var id = 123;
  data = saveArea(id); //get data from ajax request or error data?
  if (data) { 
     window.location = "/post/" + data.something
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put the redirect inside the succes callback?

Comment: You can make your AJAX call synchronous, but be mindful that any slowdowns in the data retrieval will lock up your page.

Comment: add `window.location=..` inside success field

Comment: @Ionut that was a quick usage example. The reason why I didnt put redirect inside the success callback because in some in cases I don't need to redirect it for other action.  Some places I need to use saveArea() and then redirect it, and other places I just need to saveArea() only without redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options, either run the `AJAX` call synchronously (not recommended). Or asynchronously using callbacks

Synchronous

As @Drew_Kennedy mentions, this will freeze the page until it's finished, degrading the user experience.

```
function save(id) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/post/",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            id: id,
        })
    }).responseText;
}

$('.btn-create').click(function () {
  var id = 123;
  // now this will work
  data = save(id);
  if (data) { 
     window.location = "/post/" + data.something
  }
}
```

Asynchronous (recommended)

This will run in the background, and allow for normal user interaction on the page.

```
function save(id, cb, err) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/post/",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            id: id,
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            cb(data);
        },
        error: err // you can do the same for success/cb: "success: cb"
    });
}

$('.btn-create').click(function () {
  var id = 123;
  save(id, 
    // what to do on success
    function(data) { 
      // data is available here in the callback
      if (data) { 
          window.location = "/post/" + data.something
      }
    },
    // what to do on failure
    function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: doesnt `save` function require a call for error ? shouldnt it be `saveArea(id, function(data){....} , function(data){alert'fail');} `

Comment: It's optional, `JavaScript` won't complain if you don't specify it until the `AJAX` call actually fails. I'll add it though for clarity, thanks!

Comment: no problem, it's a new information, thank you though !

Comment: Is save = saveArea()   ?

Comment: @shotor..you write async: false which make it synchronous request.. but you said it is Asynchronous (recommended) ..?

Answer (score 0):

Just make things a bit simpler.

For starters just add `window.location = "/post/" + data.something` to the success callback.
Like this:

```
function save(id) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/post/",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            id: id,
        }),
        success:function(data){
            window.location = "/post/" + data.something
        }
    }).responseText;
}
```

Or by adding all your Ajax code within the click event.

```
$('.btn-create').click(function () {
   var id = "123";

   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/post/",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        id: id,
    }),
    success: function (data) {
     window.location = "/post/" + data.something
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  });

}
```